# VS 2012 missing prerequisite error

Tags: azure

I am using visual studio 2012. I have already installed the Windows Azure SDK on my system. I am still getting the following error:

> The system is missing a prerequisite to execute the service
>   .IISExpress Development certificate is not installed.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check does your system met all the [requirements of installing Azure SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=40893)

If your system meets all the requirements, then try to install the missing components from [Web Platform Installer of Azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/downloads/)